# Finding pointer to maximum value of array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, max

I have written a function that should "return" the pointer to the biggest value of the array

```
void findMax(int arr[], int n, int* pToMax)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return;   

    pToMax = arr;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > *pToMax) {
            pToMax = arr + i;
        }
    } 
}
```

And in main I'm calling it with

```
int nums[4] = { 5, 3, 15, 6 };
int* ptr = nums;
findMax(nums, 4, ptr);
```

However, it seems like the pointer value isn't getting changed from the function which leads me to believe the third parameter might have to be a pointer to a pointer. But I thought that whatever is done with a pointer in a function changes the pointer (like with references)

EDIT: redid the function

```
void findMax(int arr[], int n, int** pToMax)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    return;

    pToMax = &arr;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > *(*pToMax)) {
            *pToMax = arr + i;
        }
    }
}
```

And now I'm calling it like this

```
int nums[4] = { 5, 3, 15, 6 };
int* ptr = nums;
findMax(nums, 4, &ptr);
```

Comment: What did you observe when you changed it to be a pointer to a pointer, or a pointer reference?

Comment: Basic stuff: any changes made to `pToMax` won't be visible outside the function. Any changes to `*pToMax` will be.

Comment: @Tas it didn't seem to have an effect

Comment: You are passing your pointer by value not by reference so pToMax is a copy of ptr that only exists in your function. Change the parameter to int* &pToMax and it should work. I'll elaborate later if this question is still up.

Comment: `int* ptr = std::max_element(nums, nums + 4);`  -- No function needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `if (n <= 0)` it is taken care of with the loop condition

You don't need `pToMax = arr;`, you are doing it before calling function

To pass pointer by reference so that you could modify it, use `int *&pToMax`

```
 void findMax(int arr[], int n, int *&pToMax)
 {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > *pToMax)
            pToMax = &arr[i];
    }
 }
```

To call it:

```
int nums[4] = { 5, 3, 15, 6 };
int* ptr = nums;
findMax(nums, 4, ptr);
std::cout << *ptr; //15
```

Answer (score 2):

Killzone Kid posted a working solution using a pointer passed by reference. Your second attempt was actually on the right track also. You just made one small error when you reassigned `pToMax` so that it no longer pointed to `ptr` but instead pointed to `arr`. Instead you should have dereferenced `pToMax` to point `ptr` to `arr`. Here's a tested and working solution:

```
#include <iostream>

void findMax(int arr[], int n, int** pToMax)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    return;

    *pToMax = arr;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > *(*pToMax)) {
            *pToMax = arr + i;
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int nums[4] = { 5, 3, 15, 6 };
    int* ptr = NULL;
    findMax(nums, 4, &ptr);

    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to just do `*max_element(nums, nums + 4)` since you're just using an array of integers.

Pretend you have the array `int num[5]={1, 5, 6, 2, -1}`;
Instead of your function, you could have a one-line command using the built-in C++ function max_element.
To find the max element, you could just say `int theMax = *max_element(num, num + 5);` and you would be done.

Here is a sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num[5] = {1, 5, 6, 2, -1};
    int theMax = *max_element(num, num + 5);
    cout << theMax << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused...where is this supposed to be?

Comment: Pretend you have the array int num[5]={1, 5, 6, 2, -1};
Instead of your function, you could have a one-line command using the built-in C++ function max_element.To find the max element, you could just say int theMax = *max_element(num, num + 5); and you would be done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Do you need elaboration? Plz upvote btw :)...only if it works for you, though.

Comment: `std::begin` and `std::end` are also helpful here. They remove the need for magic variables in the call to `max_element` so long as you have an array and not a pointer to one.

Comment: Integer arrays do not have a .begin and a .end function. I think you mean vectors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I present a solution to your problem below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int * findMax(int arr[], int n, int* pToMax)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return pToMax;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > *pToMax) {
            pToMax = arr + i;
        }
    }

    return pToMax;
}

int main() {

  int nums[4] = { 5, 3, 15, 6 };
  int* ptr = nums;
  cout << "Big is " << *findMax(nums, 4, ptr) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Please observe that: when you create a pointer with assignment to an array, it assumes the initial position by default, so the assignment `pToMax = &arr;` inside the function is not necessary.

Another thing to understand is that you are not using 2D arrays, so `int** pToMax` is completely out of scope of this issue.

Check the solution above. Hope it helps you.

**Note:** This problem does not require the usage of pointers at all. But if your study is focused on understanding pointers, then this solution will work for you.